# why does my teacher define PrintWriter this way

Tags: java

I'm taking an intro java course and my teacher uses PrintWriter like this:

```
String fileName = "chars.txt";
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
```

From the examples i've seen online, it seems people use one or the other. What I want to know is why he assigns FileWriter to PrintWriter like that? Not really a big deal it just bugs me and i want to know what's going on.

It's an online course and the teacher doesn't answer questions anymore.

Comment: You know, the best person to ask about this is your teacher.

Comment: it's an online course and the teacher doesn't respond to the questions anymore or update things.

Comment: Are you sure he didn't use `new File(fileName)`? Or `new FileWriter(fileName, true))`? As shown in your post, it doesn't make much sense. But the option for appending is only available at the "file" level of writers.

Comment: the code in my question is the code he uses. but i think what you said maybe sort of answered my question: the FileWriter is used to open/append the file and PrintWriter is used to actually print the data to file?

Answer (score 0):

A `FileWriter` is used to a named file (`chars.txt` in this case). While a `PrintWriter` is used to make it easier to use an `OutputStream` by adding `print` methods.

Now there is a constructor to `PrintWriter` that takes a file name. So it would be a little more code efficient (but no difference on runtime) to use the `PrintWriter` constructor directly. If you look at what the `PrintWriter`'s constructor does, it does more or less what your example does:

```
public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))),
         false);
}
```

What I suspect your teacher is doing is demonstrating the vast power of chaining when using the writers/streamers/etc in the Standard Java Library.

It is also very important to understand what is happening under the hood, so good question. I recommend using a good quality Java IDE like Eclipse and installing a full JDK so you can follow definitions for constructors to the Java Standard Library source code.

Comment: BTW I am pretty new on SO, so I am not sure why people have downvoted your question. Perhaps some more experienced users could explain.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) implement a constructor that takes a file name as its parameter. It may be that your teacher made an unintentional mistake or he wanted to present to you [the decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) which is used extensively by `java.io` package.